# Where can I find WebSphere configuration files?

Tags: configuration, websphere

I would like to know where are the WebSphere configuration details saved?

Specifically, configuration details that are shown in the Administrative Console (from the web) or from the console using wsadmin.

Some of the examples would be:

1. Java and Process Management: Class
   loader, Process definition, Process
   execution
2. Container Settings:
   Session management, SIP Container
   Settings, Web Container Settings,
   Portlet Container Settings

Are there XML files that persist these configuration details?

Nicholas

Answer (score 59):

WebSphere Application Server configuration data is stored in `XMI` format in the profile configuration repository.

The settings you referred to are stored in `server.xml`

```
${PROFILE_HOME}/config/cells/${CELL}/nodes/${NODE}/servers/${SERVER}/server.xml
```

Comment: I had a query. Where exactly in server.xml can I add

`-Djavax.net.debug=all`

is it in the _jvmEntries_ in the _debugArgs_ ?

Comment: @UjjwalPathak You should ask a new question rather than commenting on a 6 year old answer.  You should not directly edit server.xml; you should use the admin console or wsadmin.

Comment: Thanks Brett. I actually did that ... I was just googling that when I stumbled upon this question .... :)

Comment: If you link the question, I can give more details.  (I happen to still be on the site, so I noticed your comment.  Otherwise, it's likely no one will notice/respond to your comment on such an old answer, which is why you're better off asking a new question and linking to the old question/answer.)

Comment: Hi Brett, here's a link to the question
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37020674/where-exactly-in-server-xml-can-i-add-djavax-net-debug-all-is-it-in-the-jvmentr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37020674/where-exactly-in-server-xml-can-i-add-djavax-net-debug-all-is-it-in-the-jvmentr)

Answer (score 6):

Along with server.xml @ ${PROFILE_HOME}/config/cells/${CELL}/nodes/${NODE}/servers/${SERVER}/server.xml, there are other files too which save more data as below:

1. resources.xml at the same path. This file has all the resources information saved.
2. variables.xml at the same path. This file saves the variables used in places like DB drivers etc.

Also, there are other important file mentioned here - https://websphereapplicationservernotes.wordpress.com/2012/12/13/websphere-application-server-important-files/

As the URLs get obsolete these days, I am pasting the content here too:

CELL-scope

• admin-authz.xml
Contains the roles set for administration of the Admin console.
/appsrv01/config/cells//

• profileRegistry.xml
Contains a list of profiles and profile configuration data

• resources.xml
Defines operating cell scope environmental resources, including JDBC, JMS, JavaMail, URL end point configuration, and so on.

• security.xml
Contains security data , including all user ID and password information.

• virtualhosts.xml
Contains virtual host and Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions (MIME)-type configurations.

• variables.xml
Contains cell level WebSphere variables

• wimconfig.xml
Contains the federated repository configurations for global security
/config/cells//wim/config/

NODE-scope

• namestore.xml
Provides persistent JNDI namespace binding data

• resources.xml
Defines node scope environmental resources, including JDBC, JMS, JavaMail, URL end point configuration, and so on

• serverindex.xml
Specifies all the ports used by servers on this node

• variables.xml
Contains node level WebSphere variables

SERVER-scope

• resources.xml
Contains the configuration of resources, such as, JDBC, JMS, JavaMail, and URL end points at server scope

• server.xml
Contains application server configuration data

• variables.xml
Contains server level variables