# Where exactly in server.xml can I add -Djavax.net.debug=all is it in the jvmEntries in the debugArgs?

Tags: java, debugging, websphere, websphere-6

I wanted to add the following JVM arguments to get more detailed logs in IBM WebSphere 6

```
-Djavax.net.debug=all
```

Should I add it to the `genericJvmArguments` or the `debugArgs` option.
More specifically should I just edit the `server.xml` or use admin console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you use the admin console rather than edit the `server.xml`.

In the admin console you will:

1. navigate to `Servers > Application Servers > ServerName > Server Infrastructure: Java and Process Management > Process Definition > Java Virtual Machine > Custom Properties > New`
2. Use property name `javax.net.debug` and as a value you will use `true` (In all examples I have seen when configuring WebSphere you should use the value `true` but Java documentation use the value `all` instead. More about it in [this IBM technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21667415)

Now if you prefer to do it in your server.xml anyway, you would set it in `genericJvmArguments` as described in [this IBM technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21680514)

On another note, WebSphere Application Server v6 and v6.1 has reached their end of support a long time ago. You should really look into upgrading to a more current version.

- [IBM software support lifecycle - WebSphere Application Server 6.0.x](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/support/lifecycleapp/PLCDetail.wss?q45=G129139V43970D07)
- [IBM software support lifecycle - WebSphere Application Server 6.1.x](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/support/lifecycleapp/PLCDetail.wss?q45=B529169M78514S64)